# Empty the List<String> at the beginning of for loop

Tags: java, android, for-loop

I have a for loop and it has a List, I want to make it empty every time the for loop starts.

I have this globally,

```
List<String> topDescription = new ArrayList<String>();
```

This is the for loop,

```
  for (int j = 0; j < subMenuArray.length(); j++) {
            JSONObject subMenuObject = subMenuArray
                    .getJSONObject(j);

            if ((subMenuObject.getString("Description"))
                    .equals(sizeSelectedItem)) {

                //empty the topDescription here

                JSONArray extraItemEntityArray = subMenuObject
                        .getJSONArray("ExtraItemEntity");

                for (int k = 0; k < extraItemEntityArray.length(); k++) {
                    JSONObject objectE = extraItemEntityArray
                            .getJSONObject(k);
                    if ((objectE.getString("Description")) != null
                            && (objectE.getString("Type"))
                                    .equals("E")) {

                        topDescription.add(objectE
                                .getString("Description"));

                    }

                }
                break;
            }

        }
```

Comment: so what is the problem initialize it after loop starts

Comment: tried to clear list values with   topDescription.clear();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following is the code, but I'm not sure what you are looking for coz, every iteration it makes the list empty.

You can do this in two ways, one is just clearing and other is assigning new arraylist,

```
topDescription.clear();
```

or

```
topDescription = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

Answer (score 0):

why not make a new reference and leave the old object to the garbage collector?:

```
topDescription = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating new reference, clearing the existing List is good.  It reuses the already existing reference in the java heap but clearing the contents present in the list which makes the list to reuse with additonal overhead to JVM.